# increase the animation-duration by an unknown number sass

Tags: wordpress, animation, sass

I want to increase the animation-duration by an unknown number. This is what I have:

```
@for $i from 1 through 10 {
    .rw-words span {
        animation: rotateWord 27s linear infinite 0s;
        &:nth-of-type(#{$i}) {
           animation-delay:$i * 3s;
        }
    }
}
```

This works as far as the upto 10 items, but I need to be able to increase the animation-duration for each item but do not know how many items there will be. This is for a WordPress site looping through posts, there could be 10 or 200.

Comment: Am I correct in understanding you are trying to animate up to 200 text elements?

Answer (score 1):

SASS gets precompiled to plain CSS, which is later loaded and parsed by the browser. There is no possibility to get the count of elements, because at the time it is compiled, they are unknown.

Answer (score 0):

As Andés Andrade said, Sass got compiled to pure CSS, and it has no clue about how much element you can have.

There is, to me, 2 ways to do this.

---

The first one, is to make a "Max animation scenario" meaning that you hard code in your loop : `@for $i from 0 to 500` ( 500 or 200 )

But you may end up with a lot of unused css.

---

Or you can use javascript, which is, to me, the best option. 
You'll count how many item you have, and depending on the order, you change the animation delay ( `item.style.animationDelay = i * 3` )